# external javascript loading but not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a java script that is embedded in the html file with the script tag and it works fine. javascript code is for smooth scroll into the top of the page when a link is clicked.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 $(".scroll").click(function(event){
 event.preventDefault();
 //calculate destination place
 var dest=0;
 if($(this.hash).offset().top > $(document).height()-$(window).height()){
      dest=$(document).height()-$(window).height();
 }else{
      dest=$(this.hash).offset().top;
 }

 //go to destination
$('html,body').animate({scrollTop:dest}, 1200,'swing', function() {
    $('input#Name_First').focus();
});

});
</script>
```

But when I try to have it as external java script it doesn't work.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="$!{cdnServerPath}css/lp/js/action.js"></script>
```

code in action.js file

```
 $(".scroll").click(function(event){
 event.preventDefault();
 //calculate destination place
 var dest=0;
 if($(this.hash).offset().top > $(document).height()-$(window).height()){
      dest=$(document).height()-$(window).height();
 }else{
      dest=$(this.hash).offset().top;
 }

 //go to destination
$('html,body').animate({scrollTop:dest}, 1200,'swing', function() {
    $('input#Name_First').focus();
});

});
```

Following are the things I noticed.

- I am including the jquery -2.1.1.js file before the action.js is called.
- action.js is being loaded- I checked it in the net tab of firebug.
- I put a random alert statement in action.js. It is being triggered when the page is being laoded but not when I click the link.

I appreciate any help in getting this thing fixed.

Thanks.

Comment: any error in your console? also have a look at [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Comment: Try putting your code in a `$(document).ready` handler.

Comment: Where is this code located within your html document? did you place it in one place when trying it inline, and another when using the script include? If you placed them both in the same spot, it should work both ways.

Comment: @KevinB, you're right, that answer was probably wrong. I thought if the code was at the bottom of the page then the document.ready handler wouldn't necessarily need to be there in his first example, but would in an external file.

Comment: @Brandon I do think you were right, but the reason for it being different needs to be part of the answer. He probably did include the external script in the header with the rest of his external scripts, and the inline one in his body somewhere. I can't think of another reason for it to behave in this way.

Comment: Thanks, Kevin. That worked.

My inline javascript was at the end of the page and the including .js file at the top with other JS imports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The location of your script include is very important. If you include code in the header, it will not be able to access dom elements until the dom is loaded, however, if you placed it before the closing body tag, it would be able to access the dom elements immediately.

If you must place your include in the `<head>`, you'll have to wait for the DOMContentLoaded event, which with jQuery can be done using the `$.fn.ready` method.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // your code
});
```

Many more recent tutorials suggest placing your script includes before the closing body tag to allow your page content to load before the javascript loads because loading javascript is a blocking action, meaning, it will stop the downloading of all other things until it is complete. Adding it to the bottom of course also has the benefit of not needing to worry with the DOMContentLoaded event.

It also helps to have all of your script includes together and style includes together (separately) so that they will download in parallel.